# scroll view crash while use "UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiscrollview, xcode7

My app crash while use 3 views every view contain 12 button those buttons use the same images but with different Color every time so i use

```
    -(void) addViewsToscroll
    {

        NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [imgArray addObject:FirstView];
        [imgArray addObject:secondView];
        [imgArray addObject:ThirdView];



        CGSize pageSize = scrollView.frame.size; // scrollView is an IBOutlet for our UIScrollView
        NSUInteger page = 0;
        for(UIView *view in imgArray) {
            [scrollView addSubview:view];

            // This is the important line
            view.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ +3, 0, pageSize.width-6 , pageSize.height);
            // We're making use of the scrollView's frame size (pageSize) so we need to;
            // +10 to left offset of image pos (1/2 the gap)
            // -20 for UIImageView's width (to leave 10 gap at left and right)
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);
    }


-(void) setButtonsColor{
   NSString *localPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
                    NSString *imageBouton1 = [localPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%ld-shapeDisplayUrl.png",(long)button.tag]];
                    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: imageBouton1]];
                    if (imgData == nil)
                    {

                    }else
                    {
                        UIImage *tintedImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

                        [button setImage:tintedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        button.tintColor=color1;
                        button.backgroundColor = color2;
                    }

}
```

but when imaged assigned to the buttons and the Color change if i scroll from view to view The app crash .

> **Thanks For Your Help**

Comment: What's the error message when it crashes?

Comment: No message it's only crash while scroll

Comment: no any help ??????????????